# Docker: An error occurred trying to connect

Tags: docker, windows-10, dockerhub

Installed Docker on Windows with 2 additional installs, Oracle VM VirualBox and Kitematic. I've disabled Hyper-V in my Windows 10 PC. Now the problem is I can't download any Docker images from DockerHub, not even I can run the command as

```
Docker info
```

At both ends it shows the following error.

> An error occurred trying to connect: Get
>   http://localhost:2375/v1.21/info: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: ConnectEx
>   tcp: No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it.

If I run it in Docker QuickStart Terminal it works, but not working in PowerShell or in MSBuild.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723699/bamboo-docker-task-an-error-occurred-trying-to-connect-post-http-127-0-0-1/35769306#35769306 is a similar issue

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are using windows command prompt instead of Docker QuickStart Terminal see [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/#using-docker-from-windows-command-prompt-cmd-exe:3e44722f300b9d926b8a94aa7aeb0fd0) you should make following steps (assuming your docker machine has the name **default**):

1. `docker-machine start default` or create new one
2. `docker-machine ls`will show you your machine running
3. `docker-machine env --shell cmd default` and you'll see something like

   ```
   SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
   SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
   SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\Arseny\.docker\machine\machines\default
   SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
   REM Run this command to configure your shell:
   REM     FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd default') DO %i
   ```
4. Run `FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd default') DO %i`
5. Enjoy

Comment: Please let me know one thing, that when I run the command at the 4th point. It works fine on that instance. But when I restart the terminal I've to renter the given command. How do I set the permanent shell for Docker? Thanks

Comment: I'm not actually sure if the IP of DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376 is stable in each `docker-machine start default`. I'd make the script which does all commands in a batch (what actually Docker QuickStart Terminal does, I assume). You can take a look at the shell script attached to the Docker QuickStart Terminal shortcut. Don't think the comment is quite helpful :) just a hint.

Comment: I have been getting same problem on Windows 10. However when I follow steps 1-5 above, at step 2 the cmd has not come back with a response. I tried multiple times but no success. What could be the reason?

Comment: Thanks, this saved me some time!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PowerShell (in Windows 7) instead of Docker Quickstart Terminal then enter following commands step by step in your powershell terminal:

> **NOTE**: You must have to start Docker Quickstart Terminal first before
>   performing below operations

`docker-machine.exe env --shell powershell` it will display below commands on terminal:

```
$Env:DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY = "1"
$Env:DOCKER_HOST = "tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
$Env:DOCKER_CERT_PATH = "C:\Users\pratikpat\.docker\machine\machines\default"
$Env:DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME = "default"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# & "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env --shell powershell | Invoke-Expression
```

Execute last displayed command to configure your shell:

```
& "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env --shell powershell | Invoke-Expression
```

Answer (score 1):

I got same error on Windows 7 inside Docker Terminal. So I had to do the following. In case somebody like me is searching for this.

```
$ docker-machine rm default
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

Answer (score 0):

All I got to do was  to run

```
docker-machine env --shell cmd default
```

and then

```
eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)"
```

Answer (score 0):

When it happened to me I was a secondary user, in other words `Docker` installed under a different account. So I tried [re]creating the machine as Admin:

`C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker-machine create --driver "hyperv" default
Creating CA: C:\Users\nonAdmin\.docker\machine\certs\ca.pem
Creating client certificate: C:\Users\nonAdmin\.docker\machine\certs\cert.pem
Running pre-create checks...
(default) Image cache directory does not exist, creating it at C:\Users\nonAdmin\.docker\machine\cache...
(default) No default Boot2Docker ISO found locally, downloading the latest release...
(default) Latest release for github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker is v1.12.3
(default) Downloading C:\Users\nonAdmin\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso from https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v1.12.3/boot2docker.iso...
(default) 0%....10%....20%....30%....40%....50%....60%....70%....80%....90%....100%
Creating machine...
(default) Copying C:\Users\nonAdmin\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Users\nonAdmin\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating SSH key...
(default) Creating VM...
(default) Using switch "DockerNAT"
(default) Creating VHD
(default) Starting VM...
(default) Waiting for host to start...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...`

Sadly, it did not work. Even running `docker` in an Admin shell fails.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve problem on docker dekstop to;

Under Settings->General do you have Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS enabled? You need to if you want to access the daemon as described.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is exclusively for those, who are completely new to Docker, and are using Windows 10 OS. I am supposing that you've not installed Docker Desktop previously.

Step 1 : Go to Docker Website, [this link](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/)

Step 2 : Download Docker Desktop for Windows

Step 3 : Run the downloaded .exe file

Step 4 : Let it install and restart your system

Step 5 : Follow the tutorial, as they say, it'll give you an idea about Docker

Step 6 : At Last Sign up for a Docker hub Personal account

[image: See descriptive image]

Step 7 : Restart PowerShell and run `docker-compose up`