# maven package docker:build - connection refused

Tags: java, maven, docker

I am trying to directly build a docker image with maven with `mvn package docker:build`.

Docker is running and `docker ps` shows me my containers, so I assume that everything is running correctly. I do get the following error though:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.2.3:build (default-cli) on project reservierung: Exception caught: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: o
>   rg.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect ->

My first approach was that since I am working on windows I need to call the docker-machine ip address instead of localhost, but that also didn't work. I am kind of at a loss here, because I assume that it's something simple that I am doing wrong, but I cannot find anything about the connection refused error when docker is (seemingly) running properly.

I am sorry if this is trivial.

Comment: something looks weird `localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` do you have a reproducer, a Dockerfile, some `docker run` commands?

Answer (score 34):

On Windows with Docker/Hyper-V this occurred to me with com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.0.0. There is a discussion about this [on another forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/spotify-docker-maven-plugin-cant-connect-to-localhost-2375/9093/12), where they advise to turn on [image]

in docker Settings/General Tab. It worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

i solve the problem using this setting:

```html
<configuration>
 <imageName>10.10.8.175:5000/${artifactId}:${project.version}</imageName>
 <dockerHost>https://192.168.99.100:2376</dockerHost>
 <dockerCertPath>C:\Users\AtomView\.docker\machine\machines\default</dockerCertPath>
 <dockerDirectory>src/main/resources/docker</dockerDirectory>
 <resources>
  <resource>
   <targetPath>/</targetPath>
   <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
   <include>*.zip</include>
  </resource>
 </resources>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to run 'docker-machine ls' to check for the IP, if it's not a localhost address, you will need a dockerHost tag in your plugin configuration.
ex: `<dockerHost>https://192.168.99.100:2376</dockerHost>`

newest version of the plugin is 0.4.1 not 0.2.3

Answer (score 2):

On MacOs, I just set the environment variables as shown by

`docker-machine env`

When running the build from an IDE, make sure these variables are properly set.

Answer (score 2):

If docker is running of Docker for Windows, then below things need to be completed:

1. Open Docker Settings
2. Enable the checkbox - Expose daemon on `tcp://localhost:2375` without TLS

Normally, docker opens up port `2376` for docker client but for legacy or other application connect using `2375` port using TCP.
If you are using com.spotify it depends upon version also. The latest com.spotify plugin with latest docker working correctly else need to define a variable that tells the plugin to get the hostname from specified environment variable.

To set the hostname manually for the docker set the variable into the environment variable list:

```
DOCKER_HOST="tcp://127.0.0.0:2376"
```

It will work for localhost, if docker is running on another machine then set the ip of the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu 16.04, I solved it with:

```
DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock mvn clean install
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows 7 64 the docker env seems a bit tricky to install as it requires a linuxVM to run (update issues with previous vbox installation)
https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3396 )

Luckily in the docker quickstart terminal we can do:

```
   $ docker-machine.exe env
   export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
   export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.101:2376"
   export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="C:\Users\uv\.docker\machine\machines\default"
   export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
   # Run this command to configure your shell:
   # eval $("C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env)
```

showing us what to put into the plugin configuration

```
   <dockerHost>https://192.168.99.101:2376</dockerHost>
```

but only after using the advice found here:

[Docker: An error occurred trying to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071536/docker-an-error-occurred-trying-to-connect)

with the important part being:

```
Run FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd default') DO %i
```

we can run the  `mvnw docker:build` successfully in the cmd/intellij terminal :)

Answer (score 0):

Below change fixed my issue on OSX El Capitan, Docker Version 1.12.1 (build: 12133):

```
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

Please restart docker if `mvn package docker:build` still fails.

Answer (score 0):

update maven docker plugin to latest version 1.2.0. This solves the problem.

Comment: Please add relevant link to github issue to better explain how is the problem addressed.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same kind of error, and this is how I got rid of it.

Error: Cannot create docker access object  [Cannot extract API version from server https://192.168.99.100:2375 : Connect to 192.168.99.100:2375 [/192.168.99.100] failed: Connection refused: connect]

In my case, the problem was that maven was unable to connect to the docker daemon process to build the image, because of the wrong host address.

You can find the right host address of the docker daemon process, by command

docker-machine env

Output:
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"

Now, we can add below line in pom.xml.

https://192.168.99.100:2376

And, we are good to go.
Hope this would help.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by updating the `docker-maven-plugin` dependency version.

Comment: The last version is 1.2.2