# Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Microservices

Tags: java, microservices

I am building the code from the https://github.com/kbastani/spring-cloud-microservice-example and doesn't have docker installed on my windows machine. I want the source code to be executed. Could anyone please let me know how to fixed this error?

I have downloaded code using git and .git folder is present.

```
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.DockerException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.propagate (DefaultDockerClient.java:1226)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.request (DefaultDockerClient.java:1167)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.version (DefaultDockerClient.java:330)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.authRegistryHeader (DefaultDockerClient.java:1265)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.build (DefaultDockerClient.java:918)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.build (DefaultDockerClient.java:877)
    at com.spotify.docker.BuildMojo.buildImage (BuildMojo.java:532)
    at com.spotify.docker.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:322)
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:113)
    at com.spotify.docker.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${docker.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the settings of Docker desktop by right clicking on its icon in notification area and then check(select) **Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS** option

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45961484/3966432